# Do I lose materia and equipment when I lose a character?

Tags: final-fantasy-7

**SPOILER**: This question involves major plot points of the game.

> Now that I know Aeris dies I don't want to give her any equipment or materia because I'm afraid of losing it ... except at this point in the game I'm forced to have her in my party and without equipment/materia she brings my party down.

So I wonder:

> Is it possible in Final Fantasy 7 to lose equipment by giving it to a character who leaves/dies? If you can answer for Aeris only it's still much appreciated.

Comment: The funny thing is that the really big spoiler of this question appears on the teaser...

Comment: Damn, the old system used to display the first line only.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, her materia is automatically [returned to you](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/197341-final-fantasy-vii/41014882). You do lose her weapon and armor, but you get to keep her accessory.

Comment: Yeah, but losing her weapon (and armor) isn't a big deal, because it's not as useful to others.

Comment: Armor could be.

Comment: +1 that nails Aeris. Are there other cases where it happens?

Comment: I was thinking of putting Edincoat on Aeris to match her up with the rest of my party so losing armor is a big issue.

Comment: You do temporarily lose Cloud later on in the game. Obviously he keeps his weapon when you get him back, but offhand I can't remember what happens with whatever armor he had equipped. Mind you, by the time you get him back whatever he was wearing would be horribly outdated and likely useless by that level.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is yes as to armor and weapon. They can be lost.

It's also worth noting that

> there is a *very* brief time after the last Temple fight but before you lose control of Aeris where you can access the menu.  It's when Cloud and Aerith are in the pit, and is probably a fraction of a second.

You can use that to unequip the weapon and/or armor if you want to use them but don't want to lose them. However, I wouldn't count on being able to do this successfully - at the very least, have a save file ready.

[Source.](http://gamefaqs.gamespot.com/pc/130791-final-fantasy-vii/faqs/45703)

Comment: We've got an answer, eight years old, sourced, that says the opposite.  Do you have a source to back up your statement?

Comment: @Frank "You do lose her weapon and armor" says the old answer. I mostly just wanted to point out the part in the spoiler.

Comment: But frankly, I feel that answer should be closer to "yes", not "no", since (according to both our answers) some EQ *can* be lost, even if the accessory and materia can't be.

Comment: @Frank If you need a source beyond me having actually done it, it's https://gamefaqs.gamespot.com/pc/130791-final-fantasy-vii/faqs/45703 . It's a rather long walkthrough, but the relevant part is in Perfect Game Note 17.

Comment: I think I misread your answer.  Apologies.  That said, your source belongs in your answer.